Android Studio device explorer ADB FAIL response : open failed permission denied
I am trying to download a file from a real device with android 14, API 34 using android studio device explorer,
File path is : Android/data/myPackage/files/picture. I am getting below error:

Tried the following but no use:
1- This.
2- tried adb shell, then :
> a53x:/ $ su
 /system/bin/sh: su: inaccessible or not found

Noting that this was possible using Android 10.

su is only available on rooted devices and by default no Android device comes pre-rooted. Only some custom ROMS and unofficial emulators come pre-rooted.

Are you aware that Android Device Explorer on stock devices only works for apps which have android:debuggable=true in their Android manifest.xml?

Device Explorer is working fine, and I can see all files with names, the problem appears only on exporting files.

unfortunately, I implemented a share button and shared all media/pdf files through whatsaapp/email.
but did't find any way to use device explorer for non-rooted android phone device.
